# Check if user is coming over HTTP vs. remote AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way in the controller to figure out if the person is hitting an action remotely through an AJAX call, or just over HTTP? And then obviously perform different things for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup:

```
request.xhr?
```

will return `true` if the request is AJAX, `false` if not. It's equivalent to calling [`xml_http_request?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-xml_http_request-3F), which is the [documented method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-xml_http_request-3F).